# How to add a meaningful link in plugin admin panel?

Tags: plugins

I've read too many times this kind of code to add a link in plugin admin page:

```
<?php
function plugin_add_settings_link( $links ) {
$settings_link = '<a href="options-general.php?page=plugin_name">' . __( 'Settings' ) . '</a>';
array_push( $links, $settings_link );
return $links;
}
$plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
add_filter( "plugin_action_links_$plugin", 'plugin_add_settings_link' );
?>
```

What this piece of code doesn't answer is my question: how to have the link do what I want it to do.

`options-general.php?...` or whatever doesn't tell me how from a single link I can trigger a single function in my plugin.

if in my plugin file I have

```
function my_plugin_function() { ... }
```

I want the user to be able to click a link `<a href="???">Click here</a>` so `my_plugin_function` get fired.

How to do so?

Is there some url formatting which does this trick (something wich may looks like this "`plugin-call.php?action=my_plugin_function&nonce=d56f654a465e4&notarealworldexample=donttellmeaboutit`")?

**EDIT:**

Apparently I have to start a bounty to have this question answered.
The question being "How from the admin panel can I have a link trigger a function from my plugin (with an (async)postback ?)?" I think it deserves 5 billions points.
I don't have those and a mere 50 points for such a complex question would feel like a joke.

So here it is "IOU 5.000.000.000 points". The one who answer the question can have it.

Comment: A link is a link, it bring you to the link address. I don't understand what you mean with "meaningful link". You will to think in what you want to do and explain it better: for example, "trigger a function in admin when some conditions are met", "create a configuration page for my plugin", etc.

Comment: I want to trigger a custom function.

Comment: Could this be what I'm looking for while still being the right way to do it: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67916/57112 ?

Answer (score 0):

Short: You can't. Php functions can't be run "straight" from a button because they run server side. You need either to set a $_POST or $_GET (so you can run the function on the page load) or use ajax/javascript.

You can find multiple answers to this question on the site already. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button). edit: button/link, doesn't matter.

Comment: I know that. I'm talking about the wordpress workflow. How to format a url/a form so wordpress will trigger my function after postback (in opposition of redirecting to some intermediate webpage).

Comment: Oh. You could add <input type="hidden" name="my_plugin_function" value="1"> to your form and then add if (isset($_POST['my_plugin_function'])) { my_plugin_function(); } in your code I think?

edit: Yeah just realised you weren't using any forms... Well you should be able to do the same with url anyway.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but you'r thinking on a php perspective only while the whole box is actually wordpress.

Comment: Okay, true. But I'm fairly certain there isn't a magic url that will fire the function for you. :/